# Why print empty path in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
filter_option=" -name \"*\" "
file_paths=$(find "." -type f $filter_option)
echo find "." -type f $filter_option
echo $file_paths
```

> samuel@:~/.../linux$ ./test.sh
> find . -type f -name "*"
>
> samuel@:~/.../linux$

How do I fix this to get `find . -type f -name "*"` 's result?

Comment: Create a filename named `"*"` literally. `touch '"*"'`. Any filename with leading and trailing `"` will do.

Comment: I want to get the correct result, for example, ./somefolder ... 
not "*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an array:

```
filter_option=(-name '*')
file_paths=$(find "." -type f "${filter_option[@]}")
```